# Active Admin User Management List

Tags: ruby-on-rails, list, activeadmin

I'm looking to generate a list of all users signed up as well as a created date and an IP address.
The most important feature is the ability to delete users from this list.

Active_admin seems to be the best choice for this task, but I have found very few results for this scenario. I find it hard to believe because I would assume that this is a common feature.

Any suggestions or links to tutorials?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Ok, so I went and created a user resource through active admin. I.e /app/admin/user.rb

I then went and took some of active_admins demo code and trimmed it down for testing.

```
ActiveAdmin.register User, :as => "User" do

  filter :username
  filter :email
  filter :created_at

  index do
    id_column
    column :username
    column :email
    column :created_at
    default_actions
  end
end
```

But I get the error:

> NoMethodError in Admin::UsersController#index
>   undefined method `per' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation

Any ideas?

EDIT 2: I just tried:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  def index
    @users = User.find(:all)
  end 
end
```

and I get the same exact error.

EDIT3:

Found the issue. After some digging, will_paginate gem was causing the conflict!

Everything works now!

Comment: sorry, but you're doing it wrong. first: have you done `rails g activeadmin:install`? second: for the beginning, just create an active admin resource with a rake task so you are sure to have a valid template. remove your `user.rb`and do `rails g active_admin:resource user` (singular, like your model). and then visit `/admin` in your browser and see if it works. also don't forget to `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: Well, and how exactly did you solve the conflict? What alternative to will_paginate do you use now?

Comment: kaminari instead of will_paginate is the answer, I see.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/wiki/How-to-work-with-will_paginate) is how to get it to work with will_paginate

Answer (score 2):

With Active Admin, you can display data from every model you have. When for example you have a model `user` (your front-end users), you just create `/app/admin/users.rb` and put your stuff in there. Finished.

You can have a look at the code of [activeadmin.info on github.](https://github.com/gregbell/demo.activeadmin.info)

Comment: I had tried that a while ago, but it didn't seem to pull the list. It was just giving me errors. Maybe I should give that another go since I'm better versed now...

Comment: i am having the same, with the activeadmin `admin_user` model and the usual `user` model for frontend subscription and it is working properly.

Comment: check my edits please. I tried to do it again and got the same type of error.